# PHP: Regex replace word using wildcard characters in Lookbehind Assertions

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm looking to create a PHP Regex script that can match and replace words within a string.

The regex needs to match only complete words, which I can easily accomplish with:

```
/\b(SEARCH_TERM)\b/
```

The problem I am having is that some of the strings contain html elements as such as *<a>* tags and *<img>* tags, where the *href* and *src* attributes may sometimes contain the to-be-replaced word within their path.
If this word is replaced within these elements, then the link or image will no longer work.

Example, replace the word 'test' with 'SEARCH_TERM' for the following example string:

```
my test string <a href="http://www.google.com?q=my+test+string">link</a>
```

Would return:

```
my SEARCH_TERM string <a href="http://www.google.com?q=my+SEARCH_TERM+string">link</a>
```

Whereas I need it to ignore the href attribute text and return:

```
my SEARCH_TERM string <a href="http://www.google.com?q=my+test+string">link</a>
```

I've looked at using Regex's Lookbehind Assertions (As just below), but variable length wildcard characters are not allowed.

```
/(?<!(href|src)=.*)\b(SEARCH_TERM)\b/
```

Note: I specifically need to do this with Regex, and not a DOM parser.

Comment: Use [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/parsing-and-processing-html-xml)..don't use regex..Believe me,its more simple to parse html using a parser than doing it with regex

Comment: As mentioned at the bottom, I specifically need to do this with Regex.

Comment: Why is that you people always *need* to not use the better solution (which is just as supported as the less optimal solution)? What kind of limitation is preventing from using a decent DOM parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned you need to use an [html parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/parsing-and-processing-html-xml).

But if you want it

```
/\btest\b(?=[^>]*(<|$))/s
```

Above regex would match only if there's `<` or `end of string`(not line) ahead somewhere without matching `>`

---

**NOTE**

This would not work if your text itself contains `>`.

For example

```
 hello>world
```

Hence the reason you should use a parser

Comment: `REPLACE <img> other text.`

Comment: @MadaraUchiha that would be another good technique if the size of html is small

Comment: It isn't a technique. It's an easy demonstration on where your regex breaks. If you have an html tag, nothing behind it gets replaced.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha have you tried..it replaces even if there are no tags.I have used `$` if you have observed it properly.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha ok..there's 1 case in which it could break..see the note